# Bazaar: how put files from different locations in one repository?

Tags: emacs, bazaar, dot-emacs

I'm new to bazaar and would like to give it a try by storing my Emacs configuration files in one repository.

These files consist of a .emacs file in my home directory (on unixish systems) and a couple of  Emacs Lisp source files in /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp

I'd really like to have one repo because some changes in my .emacs file go together with changes in other files.

What I couldn't work out from the manual is how to get these files together. The "bzr init" takes recursively all files from the current directory; for my situation this would mean to create the repo in the root directory...

What do you recommend? Try working with symbolic links? Is there a way to associate a revision from one repo to one from another repo, so that easier solution of having two separate repos could be a way to go?

There is an additional challenge: on a Windows machine, these Emacs files sit on completely different locations. How to treat that?

I have some perforce experience: there the solution is easy: you can just define a view that maps repo files to an arbitrary location on your hard disk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more of a bzr question, but I can give you an Emacs answer.

The "new" way to structure your Emacs setup is to have a directory `~/.emacs.d` and put everything under there.  Rename your `.emacs` file to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and it will be found automatically.  Next, create a `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory (actually you can name the dir whatever you want, but `lisp` is pretty standard), and move or copy the files the `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp` files to that dir (and byte-compile them if you want to).  Finally, put `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")` at the top of your `~/.emacs/init.el` file.

Now everything is under one tree, so `bzr init` it as usual.  This setup will work on Windows also since Emacs understands `~` on there as well.

Comment: I realise this is the correct answer for a wrong question ;-)