# How to synchronize Emacs packages and settings?

Tags: emacs, synchronization

i have emacs at home and at work. How to synchronize them if i add new package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use git to keep my configs, and split out platform/machine dependent parts into separate files, and load them depending on machine's name.  You can see my configs [here](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master)

Comment: Resurrecting a long dead thread - if you want to keep your repo private, [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) provides unlimited free private repositories (as of Dec 2013).

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could install [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) and put your emacs configuration in the Dropbox directory. It would be the same idea as for [SyncFirefoxBookmarks](http://wiki.getdropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncFirefoxBookmarks). Your `.emacs` would just refer to the files in the dropbox directory.

On Linux you could have it even a little easier, you would just copy your `~/.emacs.d` to the dropbox directory and create a link instead. Than you could skip `.emacs` and just use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (see [Emacs Manual - Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File)).

Comment: on Windows, do you just cut and paste the `.emacs` folder and `.emacs` file to the dropbox folder?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a git/cvs/subversion/etc. repository, and simply use the version control system to allow you to update the files/directories for both places.

There's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993707/bazaar-how-put-files-from-different-locations-in-one-repository/995218#995218) to a question as to using bazaar in just this way.  That answer does a great job of explaining the directory structure to use such that it's clear where all the packages and initialization files go.

As far as how/where to store the repository, I don't know the best answer for that.  If you're often connecting to work (through a VPN or somesuch), then I'd recommend hosting the repository at work.  If not, then you could use [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/) or some other similar site - but you'd then be exposing everything to the world... Perhaps this part of the question is best asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: There are some free (i.e. upgradable to paid version) repositories out there that can be made private, so that your files are not there for anyone to look. I use unfuddle.com to version control my emacs config files, but there are a few other options.